# Java 8 LocalDate displaying in swagger

Tags: java, documentation, swagger, microservices, swagger-2.0

I have a DTO which contains field of Java 8 LocalDate type. With Jackson annotations it's possible to set format to `ISO.DATE` and everything works good. But Swagger (I have version 2.+) see the `LocalDate.class` as object

```
LocalDate {
month (integer, optional),
year (integer, optional)
}
```

(That's true but...) I want to dipsay this as string with format as it works with `util.Date`.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing same problem, so I added

```
@Bean
public Docket docket() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("name")
                .directModelSubstitute(LocalDateTime.class, String.class)
                .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class)
                .directModelSubstitute(LocalTime.class, String.class)
                .directModelSubstitute(ZonedDateTime.class, String.class)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                .paths(paths())
                .build();
}
```

in docket configuration.

`directModelSubstitute` makes swagger to treat `LocalDate` as `String` class

Comment: please indent your code properly to prevent scrolling